# Not able to call protected method of parent page in asp.net Usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have ASP.NET Page (`MyPage.aspx`) inherited from base Class: `MyBase.cs`

This Page has 1 user Control : `ChildUser.ascx`

MyBase has one Protected Method

```
  protected string GetInviteeUserType(bool mustExist)
  {           
     return "Test";
  }
```

When UserControl try to call this method like below

```
string userType = (Page is MyPage) ? ((MyPage)Page).GetInviteeUserType(): "Empty";
```

I am getting error says `This method is inaccessible due to protection level`.

So how can I call this base method in user control without making it "`public`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Page is able to call the method, but your UserControl cannot, because the method is `protected`. You could use `internal protected` to allow you to call the method from anywhere within your assembly instead.